# How to accept input into array and sort it?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

How to accept input into array and sort it?

Good day, I am new to programming and new to Python Language.

I would like to try to code the user is asked to input 10 numbers and then display it in ascending order. I am not sure on how to make this work. Here is what I have:

```
print("Input 10 numbers:")
num = list(map(int, input().split()))
num.sort()
print("Element value in ascending order:")
print(*num)
```

But this code is list. I need to accept the input and then make it as an array and then sort it into ascending. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with your code now? **It works** as expected for me.

Comment: Your code gives a sorted list already, you seem to be asking how to convert it from a list into an array?

Comment: Python lists ARE arrays.  There isn't a separate array data type.

Comment: @Tim Roberts https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: print(*num, sep='\n')?

Comment: @Passerby Not helpful.  You and I both know that's not what was meant here.

Comment: @Tim Roberts You may know what's in the OP's mind, but I don't, that's why I asked for clarification. The question mentions both arrays and lists, and says it wants an array not a list.

Comment: @Passerby yes. I am not sure but what I wanted was a one dimensional array thats why I asked to convert it into array

Comment: The problem is, you don't yet know Python well enough to know what you want.  What you have IS a one-dimensional array.  It is created, iterated and indexed like an array.  It happens to be called a "list", but it is what every other language would call an array.  Now, **IF** you are going to be using `numpy` to do numerical analysis, then there's another step needed, but for a beginner problem, you already have what you need.  You have an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so like this:

```
nums = input()
# say user inputs 1 2 3 4 ....10
nums = nums.split() # converts it to a list of strings
nums = [int(num) for num in nums] # convert them to ints
print(sorted(nums))
```

You can also test if the strings can be converted into ints or not to make you code more robust.

Comment: His code is already working. need clarification on the question maybe.

Comment: This code worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @Spooderman I’m a bit confused. The original code you posted above gives the same result as this one. What did you like about this one?

Comment: I dont really know. It just works for me also. May I ask, is this a one dimensional array?

Comment: @Spooderman Python doesn't  have *array* as a base type (though if you need the speed and efficiency of an array there is the `array` module). Python has *lists* and they are always one dimensional. If you need 2 dimensions the you create a list of lists. Calling a list an "array" is only helpful when comparing different languages.  It is likely to just cause confusion if you are working in Python.

Comment: I need the code to be a one dimensional array that is why I am asking for other opinions because I am a beginner only